# how to Delete blank page form pdf using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I am generating the PDF in that, i have merged first RDLC(Report) and second cristal report Total 2 pages are in my report,but after generating PDF it is showing three page, last page is blank so how to Delete blank page Using VB.NET... please help me out....

Comment: Probaly the easieset way would be to use the library ItextSharp. This library was written for C#, but works just fine in Vb.NET

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the third page is probably an element of the report overflowing invisibly somewhere. Try making it slightly less wide for starters and see if that helps.